# Getting the text of all check boxes in a tabcontrol to a string

Tags: tabcontrol, checkbox

I am extremely new to all of this, and whilst I have tried searching I cant find anything that has helped me achieve what I am after.

I have a form in VB with the following:

1 x tabcontrol
10 x checkboxes which sit in various tabs on the tab control
1 x listbox

When i tick any of the check boxes, I want their text to be added to the listbox, and when I untick, their text to be taken from the listbox.

I can achieve this very easily using if statements for the changedcheck event for each checkbox but I have to do that for every single checkbox which isn't very efficient as potentially i could have 20,30 40+ check boxes.  Plus if I add one at a later stage I would have to remember to add its code.

Ideally i want a method that's says: check all the checkboxes in tabcontrol if there value is true write their text to a string, if there value is false, take there text from the string.  put the string in the listbox.

I started with something like this...

```
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim txt As String = ""
For Each chk In TabControl1.Controls
    If chk.Checked = True Then
      txt = txt + chk.Text +vbCrLF
    Else
      txt = replace(txt, chk.text + vbCrLf, "")
    End If
Next
      End Sub
```

First problem is that the above obviously doesn't work! so any guidance there is appreciated - i put it together from reading scraps from other code.

Second problem is, i can't get my head round how the list box will be updated, as previously i was using the CheckedChanged event for each control, which if i do what i want, then there wont be a specific CheckedChanged event, as it could be any of the checkboxes (hopefully that makes sense!).  I don't want to have to press a button to add the checked checkboxes to the listbox, i want it to be dynamic

any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem add

```
Dim chk As Control
Dim txt As String = ""
For Each chk In TabControl1.Controls
If TypeOf chk Is CheckBox 
  If DirectCast(chk, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
    txt = txt + chk.Text +vbCrLF
  Else
    txt = replace(txt, chk.text + vbCrLf, "")
  End If
End If 
Next
  End Sub
```

For your second problem in CheckedChanged event you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub OnCheckedChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
 Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

  Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(s, CheckBox) 
   Dim txt as string
   If c.Checked = True Then
   txt = chk.Text
  EndIf

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot @jacob Seleznev for the response, I can see what you have done with the TypeOf, though since all the controls in my tabcontrol are always checkboxes i wouldnt have thought it needed that? - though i will take your word for it as clearly dont know any better!  Unfortunatly i get the following when using your modified code...checked' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.  This is probably something very basic i should know, could you point me in the right direction?  THanks again

Comment: @StephenDraper You need to type cast chk to CheckBox. See my edited answer.